# Converting NSData to AVAudioPCMBuffer

Tags: avfoundation, mp3, avaudiopcmbuffer

I've got a data stream, specifically coming from an MP3 stream.
In an attempt to convert it to an `AVAudioPCBBuffer`, I'm creating an AVAudioFormat to describe it as follows:

```
AVAudioFormat* format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithStreamDescription:&description];
```

when printing format the output is:

```
<AVAudioFormat 0x2818944b0:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame>
```

Now, when I'm trying to initialize the `AVAudioPCMBuffer` like this:

```
AVAudioPCMBuffer* pcbBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format frameCapacity:frameCount];
```

I get an exception:

```
required condition is false: isPCMFormat(fmt)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong `AVAudioBuffer` subclass. `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is for uncompressed "Pulse-code modulation" audio. You want `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` instead.